# How can I say "to feel comfortable"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that *komforta* means comfortable, as in "This chair is comfortable". I am looking for a way to say "I feel comfortable". I suspect that *mi sentas min komforta* and *mi komfortas* are wrong. How then, should I say?

Answer (score 5):

Efektive, „komforta” rilatas nur al aĵoj. En la tuta [tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/) la vorto „komforta” aperas 88 fojojn, sed ĉiam ligita al objekto, ne al persono. La anglan *I feel comfortable* oni povas esprimi kiel „mi sentas min kontenta”, „mi sentas min bona”, „mi fartas bone”.

Answer (score 4):

"Comfortable" in the sense you're talking about can be expressed as *kontenta* or *trankvila*.

Answer (score 2):

*Komforta* is now used very frequently to mean *en komforto, ĝuanta komforton*, as in English. For the most part I would say *en komforto*, or rephrase along the lines of *sidi komforte* etc. I think you could say *Mi sentas min komforte.* But *komforta* seems to be well-established.

> “Ĉu vi sentas vin komforta sur kvar piedoj?" — "Mi estas komforta, via Moŝto. Dankon."
>
> <sub>From [*La kaptilo de Dio*](http://esperanto.net/literaturo/bk/verk/kaptdi.html), by Marjorie Boulton (prize-winning story in the *Belartaj Konkursoj*)</sub>

Some other random examples: *Bonvolu komfortigi vin, gesinjoroj* (from *Libazar' kaj Tero*), *mi kondukigos vin al ĉambroj kie vi povos esti komfortaj* (from *La mirinda sorĉisto de Oz*), and *Ni devas honti resti ĉi tie komfortaj* (from *La malta revo*).

Dictionaries seem to be divided on the subject of whether this is okay. It seems fairly obvious that objects provide comfort, and people enjoy the comfort, but *komforta ĉevalo* ("comfortable horse") has the same ambiguity as the English.

Similarly, I remember seeing *komforti* (not defined in PIV) used both for *enkomfortigi* and *komfortoĝui*.

If it bothers you, and you need an one-word adjective, just say *enkomforta, -i*, etc.

Comment: *Enkomforta* seems really strange to me. I don't think I would have understood it without an explanation.

Comment: Ĉu vi povas pruvi vian eldiron per frazoj de bonaj aŭtoroj, Andrew?

Comment: Jes, tre facile.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer, but a long comment:

There are a number of ‘double-direction words / expressions’ in English. For example:

1. ‘comfortable’ (the chair is comfortable, or, I am comfortable in that chair)
2. ‘curious’ (it is a curious painting,, or, I am curious about that painting)
3. ‘read’ (I read the book, or, the sign read ‘No Trespassing’)
4. ‘ship’ (I will ship your order tomorrow, or, Your order will ship tomorrow)
5. ‘determined’ (He was determined to be the winner – he steeled himself to the task, or, the judges thought him best)
6. ‘rent’ (to allow use of property in exchange for money, or, to obtain use of property in exchange for money)
7. ‘smell’ (to sense in a way akin to taste, or, to stimulate the sense of smell)
8. ‘look’ (I will look at the picture, or, that jacket will look good on you)
9. ‘make’ (to cause to come into being, or, to attain – e.g., ‘make a shortlist’ (to succeed in being considered a prime hiring candidate by a prospective employer, or, to create a list of employment possibilities that you want to explore in more detail later).
   keywords: Linguistics
10. ‘your student’ – someone whom you are teaching, or your child referenced by the administration of the school that you child attends

Comment: Estus pli relevanta respondo kaj tre lerniga se vi aldonus la tradukojn en esperanto. Ekz scivolema, kurioza ktp. :)

Comment: @Antonia Montaro: Vi estas prava, sed tio estos tasko por alia tago.